# Python , create Matlab's like Dynamic cell array

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, cell-array

hello I should translate the following matlab code in python, it use dynamic cell array:

```
NUM=zeros(size(CELLin));    NUM=NUM(:);
jALL=cell(0,0);
r=0;
for k=1:size(CELLin,1)
    r=r+1; NUM(r)=(numel(CELLin{k,1})-1)/2; % Ak NoptN
           jALL{r,1}=[k 1];
    r=r+1; NUM(r)=(numel(CELLin{k,2})-1)/2; % Ak NoptP
           jALL{r,1}=[k 2];
end
```

Thanks in advance for support.

Comment: Can you give a sample `CELLin` (and any other undefined variables) so I can at least run your code in an Octave session. It's hard to translate without a clear idea of what the code does.  (Beware, people will complain that this is not a code translation service)

Comment: Ok, CELLin is a cell array with four entry (column), for each entry we have a vector of number, which that have to increase dynamically is the number of row  of jALL cell array,CELLin is passed by input. Now I need to understand how to create in python a dynamic cell array, so that this can be useful also to others users.

Comment: The closest thing in Python to a cell is a list.

Comment: Technically you can't dynamically change the size of a matrix or cell array in MATLAB. MATLAB does a slow and expensive copy behind-the-scenes, which is why the MATLAB editor will warn you when it notices you doing it.

Answer (score 0):

If I define

```
CELLin = {[1,2],[1,2,3];[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]}
```

and run your code in Octave I get

```
>> NUM
NUM =
   0.50000
   1.00000
   1.00000
   1.50000
>> jALL
jALL =
{
  [1,1] =
     1   1
  [2,1] =
     1   2
  [3,1] =
     2   1
  [4,1] =
     2   2
```

`CELLin` is a nx2 cell, and `NUM` gives some sort of mean length of the elements of the cell in a flatten layout  (n*2 rows).  `jALL` is just an indexing (possibly of the `NUM`).

Given the variable length of the elements of `CELLin` the simplest Python translation uses lists, not numpy.  Lists also allow me to accumulate results without preallocation.  For example the MATLAB code initials `jALL` as (0,0), but it grows with each `r` assignment.

```
# nested list; best equivalent to CELL
CELLin = [[[1,2],[1,2,3]],[[1,2,3],[1,2,3,4]]]

NUM = []
jALL = []
r = 0
for k, v in enumerate(CELLin): # iterate of 1st level
   r += 1
   NUM.append( (len(v[0])-1)/2.)
   jALL.append([r,1])
   r += 1
   NUM.append( (len(v[1])-1)/2.)
   jALL.append([r,2])
print(CELLin)
print(NUM)
print(jALL)
```

produces

```
1033:~/mypy$ python stack43742171.py 
[[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3]], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]]
[0.5, 1.0, 1.0, 1.5]
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 1], [4, 2]]
```

If I add

```
CELLin = np.array(CELLin)
```

it becomes a object dtype array (2d with list elements)

```
array([[[1, 2], [1, 2, 3]],
      [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4]]], dtype=object)
```

The rest of code runs the same

Comment: mmmm ok. But if i want create CELLin like a matrix rx4 where r change dynamically how can i do??

Comment: numpy has object arrays, but for most purposes they are just glorified or debased lists.  Your code references 2 columns of CELLin.  I don't know what you mean by 'change dynamically'.  Nothing in my code is tied to a predefined `CELLin` size.

Comment: In matlab: `CELLin=cell(0,0); CELLin{1,1}=2 ; CELLin{2,1}=3` i would like reiterate the same in python, without preallocate CELLin, so its row number should be change dynamically

Comment: In Python the only structure that lets you add elements by simply indexing them is a dictionary.  You can grow a list with `append` or `extend` methods.  You can cancatenate arrays to make new ones.  I suspect MATLAB is doing the same under the covers (making a new matrix).